# How to merge Array of Signals into a single Signal ReactiveCocoa 4

Tags: ios, swift, reactive-cocoa

In my setup, I have a `GridView` that consists of many `GridViewCell`s. Each cell has a `UITapGestureRecognizer`.

For convenience, the `GridView` has the following function
`func cellsTapGestureRecognizers() -> [UITapGestureRecognizer?]`
which returns the `UITapGestureRecognizer`s of all its cells (if they exist).

In the `UIViewController`, that uses the `GridView`, my goal is to treat the taps as `Signal`s. I managed to do this but with the limitation that I create one `Signal` for each `GridViewCell` which seems unnecessary.

```
func createTapSignals() -> [Signal<Position, NoError>?] {
    var signals: [Signal<Position, NoError>] = []
    for maybeTap in self.gridView.cellsTapGestureRecognizers() {
        if let tap = maybeTap {
            let signal = tap.gestureSignalView()
                .map { $0 as! GridViewCell }
                .map {$0.position}
            signals.append(signal)
        }
    }
    return signals
}
```

Is it possible to merge all the signals that are created in `createTapSignals()` such that in the end there is only one signal left of type `Signal<Position, NoError>`?

I looked into the [documentation](https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa/blob/master/Documentation/BasicOperators.md#merging), but only found the way how to merge `SignalProducers` by using `flatten(.Merge)`. Is there a similar approach I can take to merge an `Array` of `Signal`s.

Note that `gestureSignalView()` which is used in the function above returns a `Signal<UIView, NoError>` that carries the `UIView` of the `UITapGestureRecognizer` (inspired by @NachoSoto's [gist](https://gist.github.com/NachoSoto/25b0003c1b15d7d11a8d)).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found the solution myself after searching around in the [RAC Github repo](https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa/blob/master/ReactiveCocoa/Swift/Signal.swift).

The (static) function `merge` was exactly was I was looking for. It's part of the `SignalType` protocol (which `Signal` conforms to) and is implemented in a protocol extension.

So, I can just do the following:

```
let signals = createTapSignals()
let mergedSignal = Signal.merge(signals)
```

For reference, here is how `merge` is implemented:

```
public static func merge<S: SequenceType where S.Generator.Element == Signal<Value, Error>>(signals: S) -> Signal<Value, Error> {
    let producer = SignalProducer<Signal<Value, Error>, Error>(values: signals)
    var result: Signal<Value, Error>!

    producer.startWithSignal { (signal, _) in
        result = signal.flatten(.Merge)
    }

    return result
}
```

Comment: Yes, this is correct, `Signal.merge` is what you want :)

Comment: Is there any way to do this in ReactiveCocoa 3?